# Selecting across a link vs Selecting within the database

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, view

We have a view in our transaction database that is used to pull information from a number of views (i.e. view built on views).  When we access this view across a database link from our data warehouse the response time is really good.  When we recreated the view within the data warehouse based on materialized views from the transaction database, the response time completely tanked.  The first query (across the database link) ran in a few seconds.  The second one (within the warehouse itself) ran in 45 minutes (!!).  The explain plan cost for the first one is about 500.  The explain plan cost for the second one is in the 5 millions.  We have looked at indexes on the base tables (transactional database) vs the materialized views (data warehouse), and they are identical. Is it because we are creating our data warehouse resident views off materialized views as opposed to base tables in the transactional database?

Comment: The materialized view is certainly indexed differently to the access path available to your view. If you want help that you can action, I suggest you share the expanded query against your views, against your MView and the execution plans you get

Comment: Oracle does not optimize well or at all when joining across a database link. If I read your request correctly, you started with a remote view that accessed all remote tables (good, nothing joined across the DBLINK, all joins within the remote database) and switched to a view where you are joining multiple views on database A that reside on database B. At  that point optimizations go away. Do all of you work remotely (select * from remote_vw@rmtdb.world) or copy the data locally and then do your join locally.

Comment: @BrianLeach - when joining with views based on base tables across the database link, the query performs exceptionally well.  When joining with the view (based on materialized views) within the same database, they are taking 45 minutes or more.

Comment: @AndrewSayer - not quite sure what you are asking - do you want the explain plans for both?

Comment: @PamelaFarr Both slow and fast SQLs as expanded out as possible (ie if they're querying views the stick the view definition in instead, you can use https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/expand-sql-text-12cr1 for help), and the execution plans (NOT the explain plans, see https://ctandrewsayer.wordpress.com/2017/03/21/4-easy-lessons-to-enhance-your-performance-diagnostics/)

Comment: Did you want me to post something here?